# 2018 Mac Mini - Won't boot when power applied

Tags: startup, sleep-wake, mac-mini, power

I work in an environment where power is turned off to the building nightly. On previous revisions of the Mac Mini, I was able to get them to automatically boot when power is applied (in the mornings) by doing the following:

- System Preferences
- Energy Saver
- Schedule...
- Start up or wake: 4:00 AM every day (or sometime in the middle of the night)

[image: Energy Saver settings for automatic boot-up]

In that state, when power was applied at *any* time following 4:00 AM, the computer would boot.

The 2018 Mac Mini does not do this. I set the Schedule in the Energy Saver system preferences as above, but the computer does not turn on when power is applied. It **does** boot as scheduled if power is already hot, but not after.

Why would this model be different, and is there a way to restore that functionality?

Comment: What time is power restored to the building? Do other Macs with the same OS version *currently* behave differently?

Comment: Good point. These new Mac Minis are also running a newer version of OS X (10.14.4), so could be related as well. I'll try to find a unit with matched software (on older hardware) somewhere if I can. Will circle back if I get more data.

Answer (score 1):

Is `FileVault` enabled? If so, that would prevent the scheduled boot from working.

**See here: [FileVault and scheduled boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101830/filevault-and-scheduled-boot)**